# Mail excel attachment in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, file-io, mailmessage

I am trying to attach a excel file with mail, but not getting where I am doing the mistake. There is no error coming but mail does not get send. When I try to check the server path of file with file exist. it show me true, so my file path is correct.

Mail is going properly without attachment.

```
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
Msg.Subject = "User Creation";
string body = MailSending.PrepareMailBodyWith("WelcomeTemplate.htm", "LoginID", LoginID, "password", password);
            string clientCoverage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/file/abc.xlsx");
            bool isFile = false;
            if (File.Exists(clientCoverage))
            {
                isFile = true;
            }
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(clientCoverage);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            lblerror.Text = avnTutorial + isFile.ToString() ;
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, "document.xlsx");

            Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            Msg.Body = body;
            Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            Msg.From = new MailAddress("info@xyz.in");
            Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "mail.xyz.in";
            client.Port = 25;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@xyz.in", "xyz");
            client.Send(Msg);
```

I tried with without memory stream also here is the code but does not work.

Attachment attachment = new Attachment(clientCoverage, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);